# What is the impact of viewportwidth/height on Android drawables

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have an vector drawable I imported from an SVG asset. Sometimes, I have to adjust the size. Usually I update width and height. What I can't work out is how viewportwidth and height also impact the svg. It seems changing these dimensions can push the svg out of view within the visible area.

What do these units of measurement represent ? What is it's relationship with width and height respectively ? The [documentation from Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) is, (as usual), woefully inadequate. Could someone please elaborate ?

Comment: A VectorDrawable is not an SVG drawable. It's a different format.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The `viewportWidth` and `viewPortHeight` define the area of the document that the content of the VectorDrawable is drawn within.  They are equivalent to the width and height fields of an SVG `viewBox`.  Research how an SVG viewBox works if you need further explanation.

So imagine your shape is a rectangle that is 100 wide and 100 height.  Your `viewportWidth` and `viewPortHeight`should normally both be set to 100.  So that Android knows the dimensions of the underlying shapes.

The `width` and `height` attributes tell Android what the default ("intrinsic") rendering size of the VectorDrawable should be.  You can think of these like the width and height of a PNG or GIF (or SVG for that matter).

So the contents of your VectorDrawable could be defined over an area of 100x100. But if your width and height are 24x24, the contents will be scaled down from 100x100 to 24x24.

So that's why fiddling with the `viewportWidth` and `viewPortHeight` messes with the VectorDrawable.  So for instance, if you change them to 50x50, you would end up with one corner of the shape scaled down to 24x24 - instead of the whole shape.

Comment: As an added note don't fiddle with the width and height as it will give you more work when you have to update the graphic. Try to define the sizes on the views instead of the graphic.

Comment: This was a lot of words to not actually explain anything. The viewport is like the window you can view the SVG through, if the SVG is larger than the window then you won't see the entire SVG.

Answer (score 35):

Let's assume that the apple inside the canvas is your main **vector drawable**.Then **h** and **w** which are the **height** and **width** of the canvas respectively. So finally that **h** and **w** will be your drawable's `viewportHeight` and `viewportWidth` respectively

[image]

Comment: Beautiful draw :)

Comment: There's something I'm still not getting:  in this drawing,`width` and `viewportWidth` are the same (both are w).  So what's the point of having two variables hold the same value?

Comment: @SMBiggs  here "Width" will be the width of "Apple" and "ViewportWidth" will be the width of "Canvas"

Comment: This is wrong, the canvas is the SVG's size. The viewPort width and height are like the window you are viewing it through, the window can be relatively closer or further away and position at different parts of the SVG image so you may not see the image at all.

Answer (score 23):

Viewportwidth/Viewportheight are the dimensions of the canvas for the SVG paths and the width/height are the actual intrinsic dimensions of the entire drawable.

Answer (score 4):

Simply `viewportWidth` is like width of Frame and `width` like width of the picture inside that frame.

Comment: Not quite. `viewPortWidth` is the width of the frame's drawing coordinate system. The actual width of the frame is `width`.