# My Vector drawable appear very small with a high value size

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

My Vector drawable appear very small on the emulator, I can put 1000.dp width and height it is also small.

[image: With 1000dp width and height]

[image: With my custom size: see below]

Don't pay attention to the sky and the moon I'm working on.
The first image show with 1000.dp width and height and the 2nd show with my custom size (maxWidth / 1.5F for width and maxHeight / 3 for height)

Here is my code:

```
Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_book_sun),
                contentDescription = "Book",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(
                        maxWidth / 1.5F,
                       maxHeight / 3
                    )
                    .constrainAs(bookIcon) {
                        centerTo(parent)
                    },


                )
```

maxWidth and maxHeight are coming from BoxWithConstraints composable so I get the width and height of the screen and display the icon in function of screen size.

Vector drawable code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="141dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="841"
    android:viewportHeight="1189">
  // Some paths...
>/vector>
```

Comment: The "canvas" - `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` in your vector drawable is roughtly 6 times bigger than the `width` and `height` of the drawable that sits inside the canvas.  Typically they woukd be 1:1 ratio - This is not a compose issue.  I suggest you recreate the vector drawable correctly. see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357976/4252352

Comment: When I put the viewportWidth and viewportHeight the same as the width and height the image didn't show.

Comment: As i said "I suggest you recreate the vector drawable correctly." - you cant simply change these values an expect it to work, path data will not work when you simply change these values - it was created incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: Oh I see now! I made this with Inkscape and I forgot to fit the workspace to the vector. Thank you @MarkKeen !